# Identifying a text_field with no unique property

Tags: watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I have to fill in a mandatory text field and the html is as below

`<input type="tel" id="54221" class="NEdit" title="" maxlength="5" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; font-family: arial; font-size: 12px; text-align: right; width: 41px; left: 136px; top: 83px; height: 14px;">`

The `id` is dynamic and so I tried 
`text_field(:trouble, :type  => 'tel', :max_length => '5')`
and
`text_field(:trouble, :type  => 'tel', :title => '')`
and
`text_field(:trouble, :type  => 'tel', :title => '', :max_length => '5')`

nothing seems to work. Any suggestions? Please do let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an outstanding issue with locating elements by attributes like maxlength. I had run into a similar issue with tabindex (see [Issue 207](https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/issues/207)). The general issue that is still outstanding is [Issue 28](https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/issues/28).

The problem occurs when Watir converts the locator to a XPath. It ends up with an XPath where the attribute name does not match:

```
//input[@max-length="5" ...
```

One workaround is to bypass this logic and create a CSS-selector or XPath yourself. The two approaches that use maxlength could be re-written as:

```
text_field(:trouble, :css => 'input[type="tel"][maxlength="5"]')
text_field(:trouble, :css => 'input[type="tel"][maxlength="5"][title=""]')
```

The other attempt that did not use maxlength appears to work as expected:

```
text_field(:trouble, :type => 'tel', :title => '')
```

Comment: I had already tried `text_field(:trouble, :type  => 'tel', :title => '')` (see question above). But there were more than one with title = '' . So I used a index. `text_field(:trouble, :type => 'tel', :title => '', :index =>1)` is working!. Thank you very much!

Comment: is there a way to differentiate these two similar objects using their visibility? I have one object that is not visible. Please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: I have had to do it before, so the short answer is "yes". However, the solution typically depends on the page. I would suggest creating an HTML sample that shows the problem and posting it as a new question.

Comment: I have added it as a new question. The link is [StackOverflow Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26874114/page-object-gem-identifying-object-with-same-properties-based-on-their-visibili)