# Page-object gem: Identifying object with same properties based on their visibility

Tags: page-object-gem

I have a text box with the following html. The `id` is dynamic and I cannot use it.I fill some text in the text box.
`<input type="text" id="117841" class="NEdit" title="MyText" maxlength="20" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; font-family: arial; font-size: 12px; text-transform: uppercase; width: 184px; left: 28px; top: 0px; height: 14px;">`

There is a Add button and when I click that a New Tab is created. In the new tab, I will have a text box with the same properties above except that a new `id` is being created.

`<input type="text" id="118355" class="NEdit" title="MyText" maxlength="20" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; font-family: arial; font-size: 12px; text-transform: uppercase; width: 184px; left: 28px; top: 0px; height: 14px;">`

Both the text boxes are on the same page but in different tabs with one being `visible` and the other not visible. The Tabs show as divs. There is no relationship between the tabs and the fields within them. The Tabs show as below:

`<div id="117285" class="NTabTabs" style="position: absolute; overflow: visible; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1211px; height: 20px;"><div class="NTabTab" id="117285t0" style="cursor: pointer; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; white-space: pre; text-align: center; left: 2px; top: 2px; width: 101px; height: 16px; padding-top: 1px; border-top-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-left-width: 1px; border-left-style: solid; border-right-width: 1px; border-right-style: solid;">Tab#1</div><div class="NTabActiveTab" id="117285t1" style="cursor: pointer; position: absolute; overflow: visible; white-space: pre; text-align: center; left: 104px; top: 0px; width: 65px; height: 19px; padding-top: 1px; border-top-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-left-width: 1px; border-left-style: solid; border-right-width: 1px; border-right-style: solid;">Tab#2</div></div>`

How do I identify these text boxes based on their visibility?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you given a single HTML example that shows both fields? Given that there are tabs, I would think you would differentiate based on the tab element rather than visibility.

Comment: The Tabs just show as divs. I have updated the html for the tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the best approach is to find some distinguishing property between the two elements. For example, there must at least be something in the HTML that makes one visible and not the other.

However, if that is not an option, I think the only option left is to iterate through all of the possible text fields and take the one that is visible.

For example, in the following page there are two text fields with the first not being visible:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div style="display:none;">
      <input type="text" id="1">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="2">
    </div>    
  </body>
</html>
```

You could use a text field accessor that goes through the text field elements and picks the first visible one.

```
class MyPage
  include PageObject

  text_field(:field){ text_field_elements.find(&:visible?) }
end
```

When the page object is used, you will see that the `field_element` will be the second text field since it is the one that is visible:

```
page = MyPage.new(browser)
p page.field_element.attribute('id')
#=> "2"
```

Note that to keep the example simple, the accessor's block is iterating through all text fields. However, you can pass additional parameters to `text_field_elements` to be more specific about which text fields to check. For example, the following accessor would find the first visible text field with a specific title:

```
text_field(:text2){ text_field_elements(:title => 'MyText').find(&:visible) }
```

Comment: I tried it as `text_field(:text2){ text_field_elements.find(:title => 'MyText', &:visible) }` and I get an error `Watir::Exception::ObjectReadOnlyException: object is read only {:element=>#<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x..fce41b688 id="0.9848784769419581-70">, :type=>"(any text type)", :tag_name=>"input or textarea"}`

Comment: Am I passing the additional parameters in a wrong way?

Comment: The :title locator needs to be added to the `text_field_elements` method rather than the `find` method. I added the example to the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much Justin. `text_field(:text2){ text_field_elements(:title => 'MyText').find(&:visible) }` worked out for me.