# How to find specific text field with same id?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir-webdriver

I am testing this one angularjs application that has

```
text_field(:date, :id => 'transfer_date')
```

Problem is that there are two text fields with this id the reason being that the first one has ng-show = externalaccount and the second has ng-show = !externalaccount.

So when I test something that is not externalaccount, I will receive an error saying that the text_field is not visible.  However when I test externalaccount, the test will pass fine.  I looked around and found

[Page-object gem: Identifying object with same properties based on their visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26874114/page-object-gem-identifying-object-with-same-properties-based-on-their-visibili)

I tried this but it there are other text_fields on the page.  I need to find the first visible text_field that has id='transfer_date'.  How do I set this up with pageobject or step definitions?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the first visible text field with specific attributes using:

```
text_field(:date){ text_field_elements(:id => 'transfer_date').find(&:visible?) }
```

This says to find all text fields with the specific id and then from that list find the first that is visible.

Comment: I was waiting for you.. :)